# Configure multiple instances of ActiveMq listeners on multiple JVM's

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I want to configure multiple instances of ActiveMQ listeners on multiple JVM's(there is a 1-1 mapping between queues and listeners). We are separating listeners for high performance. Currently i have few options like configuring in database, spring xml and properties file. Not sure which is the best approach ... any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

configuring ActiveMQ listeners via Spring's MessagListenerContainer in Spring XML is the standard approach

see this page for more details: http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html

Answer (score 0):

you can create multiple instance of ActiveMQ, use the following steps.

- Go to your activemq directory bin folder and run the below commands

Create the Instance 1

```
cd /apache-activemq-5.8.0/bin
./activemq create instance1
./activemq setup ~/.activemqrc-instance-instance1

 ln -s /home/[yourHomeDir]/.activemqrc-instance-instance1
```

Create the Instance 2

```
./activemq create instance2
./activemq setup ~/.activemqrc-instance-instance2

 ln -s /home/[yourHomeDir]/.activemqrc-instance-instance2
```

Once above commands are executed, go to the instance2 conf and change the default port for the **openwire**, **amqp** in the activemq.xml and also change the **Connector** in jetty.xml.

You can start each instance as below.

```
cd apache-activemq-5.8.0/bin/instance1/bin
./instance1 console
```

Open a new Tab

```
cd apache-activemq-5.8.0/bin/instance2/bin
./instance2 console
```